# What is going on in this proof about finitely-generated modules?

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation, arithmetic-geometry

So this is proposition $4.8$ in Lorenzini's "An invitation to arithmetic geometry":

Let $A$ be a domain, integrally closed, in its field of fractions $K$. Let $L/K$ be a separable extension of degree $n$. Let $\{ e_1, ..., e_n \} \subset B$ be a basis for $L$ over $K$ where $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Then there exists a nonzero element $d \in A$ such that the $A$-module $B$ is contained in the free $A$-module generated by $e_1/d , ... , e_n/d$.

So in the proof they begin taking $\alpha \in L$ and representing it as a sum

$\alpha = x_1 e_1 + \dotsb + x_n e_n$ with $x_i \in K$, which can be done uniquely.

They then say, for some nonzero $d \in A$, that

$\alpha = d x_1 (e_1 / d) + \dotsb + d x_n (e_n /d)$ - so far so good.

The next claim they make I do not understand:

"We need to show the existence of a nonzero element $d$ such that $d x_i \in A$ for all $i = 1, ..., n$, whenever $\alpha = \Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i e_i$ *is integral over $A$*."

***$Q1.$ Why does this imply the Proposition?***

Moving forward, they fix an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, denote the $n$ distinct embeddings $\sigma_i \colon L \to \overline{K}$ as such, and define $M := (\sigma_i (e_j))_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$ with adjoint matrix $M^*$. They then make 2 claims.

*Claim $(i)$*: *Since the entries of $M^*$ are $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors of $M$, they are integral over $A$.*

*Claim $(ii)$: Since $\alpha \in B$, each $\sigma_i(\alpha) ,$ $  i = 1,...,n$, is integral over $A$.*

***$Q2.$ The entries of $M^*$ are sums of products of $\sigma_i(e_j)$, which, by definition of $\sigma_i : L \to \overline{K}$ land you in the algebraically closed field $\overline{K}$. What guarantees us that any of these sums of products of elements will actually be integral over $A$ seeing as they are not necessarily in $K$?***

***$Q.3$ Why would an arbitrary element $\alpha \in L$ be in $B$? If this statement is incorrect, what would make it correct, such that $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is actually integral over $A$?***

After this, they conclude that $\operatorname{det}(M) x_i$ is integral over $A$, but it may not be in $K$.

***$Q.4$ How could this be possible? Could someone give me an example? It would have to involve some complex roots perhaps...***

The rest of the proof looks tame enough given the above can be made sense of. Thank you. Let me know if someone would like a picture of the proof's text and I could maybe provide it.

EDIT: I realize that by considering $\alpha$ integral over $A$ it will definitely be in the integral closure of $A$, which here is $B$, so $Q.3$ should ask why that means that $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is integral over $A$.

EDIT2: Ok I understand that basically $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is integral over $A$, broadly, because homomorphisms commute with polynomials, so $\sigma(f(\beta)) = f(\sigma(\beta))$ and if $\beta$ was integral in the ring of coefficients of $f$, then $f(\sigma(\beta))$ witnesses the integrality of $\sigma(\beta)$ in the same ring of coefficients. So mostly just wondering about $Q.4$ now.

Also I get that $Q.1$ is because then $\alpha = \Sigma_i d x_i e_i/d$ so its an $A$-linear combination of the $e_i/d$ and so is contained in the $A$-module generated by these elements.